# What are the automated station types their meaning and how to determine the automated station type from a Metar report?

Tags: metar

aviation weather [documentation](https://www.aviationweather.gov/dataserver/fields?datatype=metar) shows that they check for 6 automated station types.

| auto_station | Indicates that the automated station type is one of the following: A01,A01A,A02,A02A,AOA,AWOS |
| --- | --- |

What are the automated station types their meaning and how to determine the automated station type from a Metar report?

The following table is what I have ascertained:

| auto station type | meaning | where to find in Metar report |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AO1 | automated station without a precipitation discriminator | there will be an AO1 after RMK |
| AO1A | automated station without a precipitation discriminator and manually augmented | there will be an AO1A after RMK |
| AO2 | automated station with a precipitation discriminator | there will be an AO2 after RMK |
| AO2A | automated station with a precipitation discriminator and manually augmented | there will be an AO2A after RMK |
| AOA | ? | ? |
| AWOS | ? | ? |
| Any other automated station types? | ? | ? |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the station is **fully automated** then the qualifier `AUTO` will appear in the observation text immediately following the timestamp, *e.g.*

> ```
> KHYS 031656Z AUTO 31011KT 10SM CLR 11/M02 A2967 RMK AO2 SLP056 T01061022 $
> ```

If the station is not **fully** automated then that qualifier will be missing:

> ```
> KAPA 031653Z 11003KT 10SM BKN200 04/M01 A2970 RMK AO2 SLP065 T00441106
> ```

Note that both of the above examples used an automated system, as indicated by the `AO2` remark. However, at Hays Regional Airport the system sent the observation into the NAS without any human observer input. At Centennial Airport a human observer checked the observation before it was disseminated and edited (or added) incomplete (or missing) elements.

If there is no automated station then there will be no `AOn` remark:

> ```
> KMWA 031745Z 31014KT 10SM BKN006 BKN011 OVC022 10/10 A2892
> ```

This indicates that the observation was composed entirely "by hand."

In my experience I have never seen the remarks `AO1A` nor `AO2A`. The manual-augmentation status is indicated by the lack of an `AUTO`. I have also never seen `AOA` nor `AWOS`.

There is no explicit flag in the observation text or remarks to indicate whether the system is an AWOS or an ASOS, only whether or not it has a precipitation discriminator. However, there is one very big clue: a fully automated AWOS issues long-line observations three times per hour no matter what; a fully automated ASOS issues hourly METARs and occasional SPECIs as the conditions dictate.